# Seeking automated toolchain for WAV cleanup and conversion to MP3 (currently using Audacity manually)

Tags: mp3, audacity, wav

I use Finale with the Garritan sounds to convert my music into WAV files; after that I manually load each one into Audacity and

1. select all
2. use the "normalize" effect (with default settings)
3. manually select the silence at the beginning of the file and delete it
4. manually select the silence at the end of the file and delete it
5. finally export the whole thing as an MP3 (with specific tag data)

This gets tedious, especially as I work on a ten-movement piece with six part-prominent rehearsal "tapes" to accompany the full-score rendition. And there are too many variations in what's going on for me to trust AutoHotKey for this one.

Is there a way to script Audacity, or is there another toolchain that would do what I want? I'm running on a WindowsXP laptop with cygwin installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More research last night led me to SoX (which is easily searched for; as a new user I can only post one hyperlink) and [tag](http://synthetic-soul.co.uk/tag/)

I was able to hook these up with a python script to iterate over the wav files and do the transformations above.